# API not allowing attribute codes > 30 characters

Tags: attributes, api, magento-2.1, rest-api, magento-2.1.1

[image]

[image]
I have tried updating the ATTRIBUTE_CODE_MAX_LENGTH value in ../magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/attribute.php. I've cleared the cache, reindexed and rebooted the server but, the changes don't seem to be working. I've tested this with an insert of 30 characters and it will accept the attribute code and insert the attribute.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.